# Running a python script in windows

Tags: python-2.7

I am new to Python.

I am executing a script in windows, but it does nothing and gives an error "invalid syntax".

Can you help me with the error. I have set the PATH variable to include my python.exe location.

Please see attached image:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your image is from the python command line, only python commands are accepted there and there is no need to specify python in the beginning (in the shell python is just a call to the python interpeter).
In order to run windows commands in python use the `os` or `subprocess` modules.